# Primefaces responsive <p:panelGrid> not working with 5 columns

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, responsive

Let's have some simple responsive primefaces `<p:panelGrid>` with 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 columns (just as an example)

```
 ...
<p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid">
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid columns="5" layout="grid">
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid columns="6" layout="grid">
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
   <h:outputText value="Column"/>
</p:panelGrid>
...
```

Probably I'm missing something...but somehow the responsive of the specific 5 columns `panelGrid` is not working properly.

Here is an screenshot:

[image]

Looking at the html, it seems to be that primefaces does not add the `ui-grid-col` class (is adding `null` instead) when there are 5 columns.

[image]

Any ideas? Maybe a primefaces bug or I'm missing something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic Primefaces Grid CSS (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) consists of 12 columns, which can be grouped together:

2 column layout -> 12 / 2 --> 6 + 6 (=12)

3 column layout -> 12 / 3 --> 4 + 4 + 4 (=12)

4 column layout -> 12 / 4 --> 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 (=12)

5 column layout -> 12 / 5 = **2.4 (no integer value!)**

Therefore Primefaces can't render a 5-column layout. But it seems strange, that it renders a `null`value instead of an empty String.

Looking into the `org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.GridLayoutUtils`class you can see the  allowed values:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> COLUMN_MAP = new HashMap();

private GridLayoutUtils() {
}

public static String getColumnClass(int columns) {
    return (String)COLUMN_MAP.get(Integer.valueOf(columns));
}

static {
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(1), "ui-grid-col-12");
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(2), "ui-grid-col-6");
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(3), "ui-grid-col-4");
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(4), "ui-grid-col-3");
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(6), "ui-grid-col-2");
    COLUMN_MAP.put(Integer.valueOf(12), "ui-grid-col-1");
}
```

So you can use the following values: **1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The advantage of 'open source'. Thanks for finding out. Maybe a github issue should be created that states this